# Str::slug alternative for hindi and arabic strings?

Tags: unicode, laravel, laravel-4, multilingual

I use `Str::slug` to generate friendly URL's, however `Str::slug()` method returns `null` on arabic and hindi strings. Probably chinese, japanese, korean and those charsets too.

For example:

```
return Str::slug('मनोरंजन'); //null
```

How can I solve this issue efficiently?

Comment: Try use other package. Example https://github.com/kevinlebrun/slug.php

Comment: I didn't find any solution for way to create Hindi and Arabic slug । Try these examples। https://technosmarter.com/qa/784/how-to-create-slug-for-hindi-language-in-php https://technosmarter.com/qa/823/how-to-create-arabic-words-to-slug-using-php hope these examples will help you and others.

Answer (score 7):

I have faced this problem when I was working with Arabic language, so I've made the following function which solved the problem for me.

```
function make_slug($string = null, $separator = "-") {
    if (is_null($string)) {
        return "";
    }

    // Remove spaces from the beginning and from the end of the string
    $string = trim($string);

    // Lower case everything 
    // using mb_strtolower() function is important for non-Latin UTF-8 string | more info: http://goo.gl/QL2tzK
    $string = mb_strtolower($string, "UTF-8");;

    // Make alphanumeric (removes all other characters)
    // this makes the string safe especially when used as a part of a URL
    // this keeps latin characters and arabic charactrs as well
    $string = preg_replace("/[^a-z0-9_\s-ءاأإآؤئبتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهويةى]/u", "", $string);

    // Remove multiple dashes or whitespaces
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s-]+/", " ", $string);

    // Convert whitespaces and underscore to the given separator
    $string = preg_replace("/[\s_]/", $separator, $string);

    return $string;
}
```

Note that this function solves the problem only for Arabic language, if you want to solve the problem for Hindi or any other language, you need to add Hindi characters (or the other language's characters) beside or instead of these `ءاأإآؤئبتثجحخدذرزسشصضطظعغفقكلمنهويةى` existing Arabic characters.

Comment: Works perfect! Just an addition, make sure to use utf-8 through PHP: `header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');` or HTML meta tag, in order for this to work.

Comment: It work nicely, but don't forget to add numbers too `٠١٢٣٤٥٦٧٨٩`

Answer (score 2):

try this:

**Save:**

```
Str::slug(Input::get('title'))==""?strtolower(urlencode(Input::get('title'))):Str::slug(Input::get('title'));
```

**Get:**

```
 $slug = strtolower(urlencode($slug));
```