# Laravel str_slug not working for unicode bangla

Tags: php, laravel

I am working in a laravel project. I have slugged url. Its working fine for English language. But while I use Bangla it returns empty. Please help me to solve the issue.

```
echo str_slug("hi there");

// Result: hi-there

echo  str_slug("বাংলাদেশ ব্যাংকের রিজার্ভের অর্থ চুরির ঘটনায় ফিলিপাইনের");

// Result: '' (Empty)
```

Comment: make sure to use utf-8 through PHP: header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); or HTML meta tag, in order for this to work.

Comment: Check this link:- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22112029/strslug-alternative-for-hindi-and-arabic-strings

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`str_slug` or facade version `Str::slug` doesn't work with non-ascii string. You can instead use this approach

```
function make_slug($string) {
    return preg_replace('/\s+/u', '-', trim($string));
}

$slug = make_slug(" বাংলাদেশ   ব্যাংকের    রিজার্ভের  অর্থ  চুরির   ঘটনায়   ফিলিপাইনের  ");
echo $slug;


// Output: বাংলাদেশ-ব্যাংকের-রিজার্ভের-অর্থ-চুরির-ঘটনায়-ফিলিপাইনের
```

Comment: use this package for bangla slug https://packagist.org/packages/sohibd/laravelslug

Answer (score 4):

certainly, this code will be suitable for any local language. you can use for unicode or any other operation. this preg_match will remove some of special character and convert seo friendly slug from your post title.

```
enter code here

     function CleanURL($string, $delimiter = '-') {
      
$string = preg_replace("/[~`{}.'\"\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*\(\)\_\=\+\/\?\>\<\,\[\]\:\;\|\\\]/", "", $string);
    
       
        $string = preg_replace("/[\/_|+ -]+/", $delimiter, $string);
    
        return $string;

    }

    $slug=CleanURL($request->title);
    $post->slug=$slug;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this; it will work properly.

```
$('input[name=title]').keyup(function () {
    var slugElm = $('input[name=slug]');

    slugElm.val(
        this.value.toLowerCase()
        .replace(this.value, this.value).replace(/^-+|-+$/g, '')
        .replace(/\s/g, '-')
    )
})
```